# Entire div is not working in Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have a page divided between two divs Ba and Bb, everything in Ba works, everything in Bb does not.  I'm in the process of dividing and conquering this problem.  Does anyone know why Chrome would effectively disable a logical division of my page and IE would not?

By not working I mean you can't click in the text boxes, nothing happens when you hover, you can't click on the buttons, etc.

Comment: This could be a variety of things - syntax is most likely. Could you post some source, or perhaps a jsfiddle?

Comment: Syntax in the xhtml, css, or javascript?  How can the problem be so widespread or is it multiple?

Comment: This would probably most likely be the xhtml. But the more available the easier it would be to figure out :)

Comment: Where do I set the browser in jsfiddle?

Comment: You don't have to set that - it will go off whatever browser the person is using.

Comment: Please post the HTML. Does Bb have different styling than Ba?

Comment: no, the only difference it has from the rest of my site is I center Bb in the body instead of a "div that covers the whole body".  I was planning on updating this for consistency so I should probably do this as a potluck try at fixing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a z-indexing issue.  There was an invisible div that had a z-index higher then everything beneath it.  Hence all the issue were only one issue.  For some reason Chrome, Opera, IE9 and likely more standards compliant browsers picked this up while older browsers did not.